# Set timezone on RedHat ubi8-minimal image

Tags: rhel

How can be the timezone set on a RedHat Universal Base Image minimal?

timedatectl command does not seems to work:

```
$ timedatectl
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to create bus connection: Host is down
```

Answer (score 4):

For the RedHat ubi8-minimal image, you need to set the timezone as an environment variable and reinstall tzdata using the following commands (Denver example).

```
export TZ='America/Denver'
microdnf reinstall tzdata -y
```

If you're building a container, the container/docker file should contain the following (Denver example):

```
RUN /bin/microdnf reinstall tzdata -y
ENV TZ=America/Denver
```

Answer (score 0):

See whether `/etc/localtime` is a regular file or a symlink. Then, accordingly copy or link the timezone file that is appropriate to your timezone (and DST rules, if applicable) from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` directory tree to `/etc/localtime`, and update your initramfs file.

Comment: There is no /usr/share/zoneinfo in ubi minimal, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5616681

Answer (score 0):

You can run `tzselect`

Or use: `TZ='(your timezone)'; export TZ`

Comment: tzselect seems not to work either: /usr/bin/tzselect: time zone files are not set up correctly

Comment: mattob, in this case it seems like you dont have a timezone files

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the timezone database under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, the timezone can instead be set with the environment variable `TZ` using the POSIX-format (see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).